# Do wild birds eat the egg shells of their own offspring?

Tags: ornithology

**Background:**

I'm a volunteer who is monitoring nest boxes that were established for American Kestrels (Falco sparverius). This spring I've cleaned several boxes that were newly-installed the previous spring, with no intervening monitoring until I showed up a year later. They were obviously used last season (poop, pellets, prey remains), but no egg shells.  So either the inhabitants never laids eggs, or they laid eggs and ate the shells.  Seems to me that the shells would be a good calcium source.

**Question:**

Do wild birds eat their offspring's egg shell?

Comment: Did you try Googling this first? I immediately came up with an answer.

Comment: This may unusual for a Q&A site, but we require evidence of an effort on the asker's part that they tried googling (or a book/whatever) to try to answer their own question. Yes/no answers here will be deleted, and this does fall into that kind of answer. The concept is that the more effort you put into your question, the more effort we put into our answers, even to the point of often/usually giving you "proof" that you can trust the answer you receive on this site. You can edit your question by clicking on the edit button. Thanks. (And what a great volunteer "job"! I'd like that.)